# Load Subcategories by id in magento1

Tags: php, magento, categories

I have a phtml file in magento..Iam using this code.But it load all subcategory.Is there any way to exclude some subcategory

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
/* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
/* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
->addAttributeToSelect('image')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
->joinUrlRewrite()
->load();

 $_categories=$collection; 

$_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() 
 foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory)
{
//need to exclude some subcategory based on its id.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may filter the categories more by:

- their level: `addAttributeToFilter('level','1')` - this will get only first level categories;
- whether they are or not included in the menu: `addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')`;

You may also further filter the categories by checking their products to see if they have **active** (status is 1) and **visible** individually and in list (visibility 4) products:

```
    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

P.S: You may want to move this business logic inside a **model** class or at least inside a **block / helper** class, in order to respect the MVC (Model-View-Controller) design pattern of the Magento 1 platform.